# What is the difference between "allen" and "alles" (genitive)?

Tags: difference, grammatical-case

2. Korinther 1:3 (Luther 1984):

> Gelobt sei Gott, der Vater unseres Herrn Jesus Christus, der Vater der Barmherzigkeit und Gott ***allen*** Trostes,

2. Korinther 1:3 (Schlachter):

> Gelobt sei der Gott und Vater unseres Herrn Jesus Christus, der Vater der Barmherzigkeit und Gott ***alles*** Trostes,

Answer (score 3):

Janka bringt es knackig auf den Punkt. Bills Frage steht auch in Zusammenhang mit dem Dauerstreit '*diese**s** Jahres*' oder '*diese**n** Jahres*'. Im Kontext dieser Fragestellung stellt die Duden-Grammatik 2006 fest (S. 268 Rz 356):

"Die Form *-en* breitet sich auf Kosten von *-es* immer weiter aus. Der Prozess begann schon im Frühneuhochdeutschen beim starken Adjektiv (...) und ist bis jetzt nicht ganz abgeschlossen. - Standardsprachlich ist nur die *s*-Form korrekt." Letzteres beziehe sich auf *der/die/das*, auf *dieser/jener* und auf Wörter nach dem Muster *ein/kein/mein*, hier wird der Genitiv also immer mit *-s* gebildet.

Weiter heißt es auf S. 269. "Vor allem in bestimmten festen Verbindungen findet sich die *n*-Form aber schon, sofern das folgende Substantiv ein Genitiv-*s* aufweist. Dieser Gebrauch ist allerdings standardsprachlich nicht anerkannt. (...) Bei den übrigen Artikelwörtern und Pronomen schwankt der Gebrauch standardsprachlich"; dann wird noch einmal erwähnt, dass die *n*-Form nur dann in Frage kommt, wenn das Substantiv ein Genitiv-*s* trägt. Als Beispiele werden genannt:

- *gleich welche**s** / welche**n** Alters*
- *die Kreativität jede**n** Schülers / die Vorfreude jede**s** Schülers*

Dies gilt soweit ich sehe in strikterer Weise auch für 'mancher/e/s' in Artikelposition:

- Die Begeisterungsfähigkeit *manche**n** Schülers* wurde auf eine harte Probe gestellt.

Hier käme nach meinem Gefühl ?*manche**s** Schülers* (heute) nicht (mehr) in Frage.

Bezogen auf die Ausgangsfrage hieße das: Beide Formen sind als Genitiv möglich, die Form 'alles Trostes' klingt heutzutage 'archaisch-fremd' und würde standardsprachlich gemieden. Aber auch ein 'Gott allen Trostes' wäre heutzutage nicht sehr zeitgemäß, man würde vielleicht eher von einem 'Gott für jede Art von Trost' sprechen (klingt flapsig durch Anklang an 'Mann für alle Gelegenheiten') oder man müsste noch umständlicher umschreiben: der 'Gott, in dem jeder Trost seinen Ursprung hat' oder ein 'Gott, der allein wahren Trost spendet'? Damit wäre jedoch der erhabene Charakter des alten Textes zerstört.

Comment: Ich hatte zuerst vermutet, es sei eine Schweizerdeutsche Besonderheit, an dieser Stelle kein -n zu verwenden.

Comment: @Janka: Könnte sein, hab dafür keine Referenz.

Comment: Der sprachgeschichtliche Hintergrund ist, dass die deutschen Adjektive (im Mittelhochdeutschen glaube ich) ihre ererbten Endungen abgeworfen und aus zwei Quellen neu bezogen haben: Aus den konsonantischen Substantiven (schwach) und den Pronomen (stark). Inzwischen breiten sich die schwachen Endungen weiter auf die Pronomen aus, ein Prozess, der noch nicht abgeschlossen ist.

Answer (score 2):

> Es handelt sich um die Wurzel alle**n** Übels.

You are right this is a genitive attribute, and it has to be a genitive in *Hochdeutsch*.

The Schlachter bible translation has a unique style, which tries to adhere to the “original text” but often enough it's just a bad translation.

Answer (score 0):

Think of as the suffix -s is enough in *Trostes* to indicate the genitive, so you don't need it in *alle* and use *allen* instead.

I never use the *alles* form, instead it sounds terribly wrong to me. I **always** use the form with *allen*.